# client certificate from a .NET 5 site to an OwinRequest in a .NET 4.7.2 site via REST communication?

Tags: x509certificate, .net-5, .net-4.7.2

I'm trying to send a client certificate from a .NET 5 app using REST communication to a FW 4.7.2 app

From .NET 5 application, I use HttpClientHandler adding client certificate from my storage of certificates. This has to be received in FW 4.7.2 app with OwinRequest.

We use HttpClient and add HttpClientHandler with certificate.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
// Add valid client certificate to handler
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
handler.ClientCertificates.AddRange(GetClientCertificate(x509AuthSettings));
// Create new HTTP Client using handler
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xmlMessage);
LoggingHelper.WriteLogsForAllLoggers($"requestUri: {requestUri}", PriorityEnum.Info, new string[] { LoggingConstants.DELIVER_MESSAGE_LOGGER });
// Create POST request to serverUri endpoint
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    RequestUri = new Uri(requestUri),
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};

// Send request and wait for the response
LoggingHelper.WriteLogsForAllLoggers($"Send POST request to {requestUri}. Timeout is set to {client.Timeout}. Waiting for response...", PriorityEnum.Info, new string[] { LoggingConstants.DELIVER_MESSAGE_LOGGER });

var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

My problem is when received the Request, the certificate emitted from client is not present. I'm trying to find in the context through the key ssl.ClientCertificate.

```
IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment = Request.Environment;

var certLoader = Context.Get<Func<Task>>("ssl.LoadClientCertAsync");
if (certLoader != null)
{
    await certLoader();
}

X509Certificate2 clientCert = Context.Get<X509Certificate2>("ssl.ClientCertificate");
```

I wan´t get the certificated emit from NET5